# `TypeError: cannot write property 'implementation' of undefined` error in frida

Tags: instrumentation, android-instrumentation, frida

I am trying to inject the below script using frida

```
setImmediate(function() { //prevent timeout
    console.log("[*] Starting script");

    Java.perform(function() {

      var bClass = Java.use("sg.vantagepoint.uncrackable1.a");
      bClass.onClick.implementation = function(v) {
         console.log("[*] onClick called");
         // do nothing
      }
      console.log("[*] onClick handler modified")

    })
})
```

Throws the below error

```
Attaching...                                                            
[*] Starting script
TypeError: cannot write property 'implementation' of undefined
    at [anon] (../../../frida-gum/bindings/gumjs/duktape.c:57636)
    at /inject.js:10
    at frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:11
    at E (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:346)
    at frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:298
    at frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:11
    at frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:278
    at /inject.js:13
    at frida/runtime/core.js:55
```

command i am using **frida -U -l inject.js owasp.mstg.uncrackable1**

Below one is the decompiled code of the apk file.

```
package sg.vantagepoint.uncrackable1;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private void a(String str) {
            AlertDialog create = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            create.setTitle(str);
            create.setMessage("This is unacceptable. The app is now going to exit.");
            create.setButton(-3, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            create.setCancelable(false);
            create.show();
        }
```

Comment: You are trying to override the method `onClick` of class `sg.vantagepoint.uncrackable1.a`. Based on the error message I would assume that this class does not have an `onClick(...)` method.

Comment: I have added decompiled code. @Robert

Comment: `sg.vantagepoint.uncrackable1.a` is a method not a class. If you want to override a method you need the class name! Trying to load it via `Java.use` will never work for what you are trying to do. You have to find out the class name of the anonymous inner class generated by `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()`. It should be something like `sg.vantagepoint.uncrackable1$<some characters>`. Use a decompiled source code that shows you the real class like smali.

Answer (score 1):

Try to inject this script

```
setImmediate(function () {
    console.log("[*] Starting script");

    Java.perform(function () {

        var bClass = Java.use("sg.vantagepoint.uncrackable1.MainActivity$1");
        bClass.onClick.implementation = function (v) {
            console.log("[*] onClick called.");
        }
        console.log("[*] onClick handler modified")


        var aaClass = Java.use("sg.vantagepoint.a.a");
        aaClass.a.implementation = function (arg1, arg2) {
            var retval = this.a(arg1, arg2);
            var password = ''
            for (var i = 0; i < retval.length; i++) {
                password += String.fromCharCode(retval[i]);
            }

            console.log("[*] Decrypted: " + password);
            return retval;
        }
        console.log("[*] sg.vantagepoint.a.a.a modified");

    });

});
```

Comment: I recommend using this tool because it has a GUI: -https://github.com/m0bilesecurity/RMS-Runtime-Mobile-Security?fbclid=IwAR0QbwgRVSh64JPo-n5xRUfYYjOv1-JRMjFq3uHQZarJFOGU4u9Vf2NSsGQ

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're trying to override the onClick function of the main activity: `sg.vantagepoint.uncrackable1.MainActivity$1` doesn't have an onClick() function. You can either cancel the function call entirely by overriding the a function to do nothing, or if you want to retain the logic but instead just cancel the display, should use `Java.choose(...)` [API](https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/) to choose the alert dialogue once it is instantiated and change it to fit your needs - for example, you can make the dialogue window cancelable, like this:

```
setImmediate(function() { //prevent timeout
    console.log("[*] Starting script");

    Java.perform(function() {

      var bClass = Java.use("sg.vantagepoint.uncrackable1.a");
      var oldImpl = bClass.a.implementation;
      bClass.a.implementation = function(v){
          console.log("Initial activity logic is launching");
          oldImpl(v);
          Java.choose("android.app.AlertDialog", {
              onMatch: function(instance){
                  console.log("Found an alert dialog, making it cancelable")
                  instance.setCancelable(true);
              }
              onComplete: function(){
                  console.log("Done")
              }
          })
      }

    })
})
```